# Why did the "Community" bot decide that this answer should be deleted?

Tags: discussion

OK, folks, this isn't any attempt to suggest new policy guidance for ASE, it's just a simple question about something that I'm curious about.

Why did the "Community" bot decide to delete this answer?

[Is it true the F-16 has never lost a dogfight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65131/is-it-true-the-f-16-has-never-lost-a-dogfight/96036#96036)

I can see why a human moderator might have some issues with the answer-- but the "Community" bot?

After all, *if* the assertions in the answer were actually true, *then* the answer would seem to meet ASE guidelines.

Was the deletion triggered by the phrase "Obviously this will be deleted immediately"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Ralph said, in the [timeline](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/96036/timeline) of the post you can see:

> 2022-11-21 18:04:03Z  history     deleted     CommunityBot        User 66330 destroyed

meaning that the post was deleted because the account was destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the account of the user who wrote the post no longer exists.  No info as to the back-story there, although [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) gives at point 13 what might be a hint.

[Further info on deleted & destroyed accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)